# Garbage Backspace Command Line

Tags: c

I have made a programm, in C, that reads commands from keyboard and writes them, it works like this:

```
put this is stackoverflow
```

- opcode: *put*
- data: *this is*
- key: *stackoverflow*

Sometimes when I' m writting the command and I do a backspace it leaves garbage:

data: a`�

The code is very complex but here are some pieces of it:

```
    printf("data: %s\n",(char*)msg->content.value->data);//data is *void

    ...
    char command[MAX_MSG];
    fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);

    command[strcspn (command, "\n")] = '\0';
    aux_command_key = strdup(command);
    aux_command_data = strdup(aux_command_key);

    if(strcmp(opcode, "put") == 0){
           sendMessage->opcode = OC_PUT;
           sendMessage->c_type = CT_ENTRY;
           char *key = getKey(aux_command_key, opcode);

           if(key == NULL){
                     printf("Invalid number of arguments.\n");
                     success = -1;
           }

           else{
                     key = strdup(key);
                     char *data = strdup(getData(aux_command_data, opcode, key));                   sendMessage->content.entry = entry_create(key, data_create2(strlen(data), data));
           }
     }
     ...
     else if(strcmp(opcode, "get") == 0){
           sendMessage->opcode = OC_GET;            
           sendMessage->c_type = CT_KEY;
           char *key = getKey(aux_command_key, opcode);

           if(key == NULL){
                     printf("Invalid number of arguments.\n");
                     success = -1;
           }

           else{
                     key = strdup(key);
                     sendMessage->content.key = key;
           }
     }
```

Is this normal or can I be doing something wrong?

Comment: show us your code where you are reading the user input

Comment: It is very complex. But I put some pieces of it.

Comment: It definitely not normal and needs to be inspected. Any compiler warnings with -Wall? It might help if you provided input your code fails processing. Anything more detailed.

Comment: Sounds like more of an issue with your terminal (tty) settings and how the backspace key is configured to interact with it.  Did you try Ctrl-H instead of backspace?  Or Shift-backspace?  If either of those work, it's likely a tty configuration issue.

Comment: `stdin` is usually buffered.  So a backspace should not appear in the buffer of `fgets()`.  Rather, backspace acts at the console and simply shortens the input by 1.  Either OP making `stdin` unbuffered or using piped input.